# HTML5 tag main correctly used?

Tags: html, w3c, semantic-markup

Please help me with used HTML5 tag `main`. Is this example used semantically correct?

```
  <main role="main">

        <article role="article">
            <h1>Heading 1</h1>
            <p>Text text text</p>
        </article>

        <aside role="complementary">
             <div class="box"></div>
             <div class="box"></div>
        </aside>

  </main>
```

---

Ok thanks, and this examle is correctly?

```
<div class="main">

    <article role="article">
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <p>Text text text</p>
    </article>

    <aside role="complementary">
         <div class="box"></div>
         <div class="box"></div>
    </aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `<main>` tag specifies the main content of a document.

The content inside the  element should be unique to the document. It should not contain any content that is repeated across documents such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information, site logos, and search forms.
source http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp

In Your example main tag contain aside, its not correct.

Comment: Why can't a main element contain an aside element? Also the first two paragraphs are plagiarized from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp

Comment: aside tag using for blocks like sidebar, main tag should not content sidebars.

Comment: While the main element should indeed not contain sidebars, not all asides are sidebars. The role="complementary" seems to suggest that this aside is in fact a sidebar, but that's due to the role attribute, not the fact that it's an aside element.